# is there a way to add registrationids for FCM topics using firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send notifications to a set of users whose details I have in a CSV, in my research, I've found that using topics is a way to go about this.
i want to accomplish what this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/topic-messaging) is doing but using firebase console. is there a way to import registration ids and group them in the console itself?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to register an FCM token for a topic in the Firebase console.

I usually have a small Node.js script locally that [uses the Admin SDK to register a token to a topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-topics), which isn't much more than (for Node.js):

```js
getMessaging().subscribeToTopic(['my_token'], '/topics/mytopic')
```